# Autosomal Inbreeding Probability Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, biology

We are mating two people with Aa genotypes.  So the punnet square tells us their offspring will be AA, Aa, or aa with probabilities .25, .5, or .25, respectively.  We are interested in breeding these offspring (we are assuming there are many offspring) together and need to find the probability we pair together (AA,AA), (AA,Aa), (AA, aa), (Aa,Aa), (Aa,aa), (aa,aa).  My attempt was to multiply the P(AA)*P(AA) and so on down the list but the six probabilities did not add up to 1, as it should.  any help is appreciated.  this is for a film project for my linear algebra II class.  thanks.

Comment: Please list the probabilities you computed for each case.  Note that $(AA,Aa)=(Aa,AA)$ so you need to double the probability for the one case to include both.

Comment: Probabilities of the pairings are as follows: (AA,AA)=.25*.25=1/16. (AA, Aa)=1/4 (AA,aa)=1/16 (Aa,Aa)= 1/4 (Aa,aa)=1/4 (aa,aa)=1/16.     It's been a late night so I'm certain it's a simple error in thought

Comment: $(AA,aa)=(aa,AA)$ so the probability is $\frac 18$.